# Динамическая загрузка текстур в OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl

Всем доброго времени суток. Появилась такая проблема:
Нужно динамически менять текстуру для примитива. Т.е. предварительно есть 4-5 текстур. Нужно во время работы программы изменять текстуры у примитива.

Все найденные мною мануалы показывают применение текстур на примере VAO, где текстура лежит в массиве с координатами/цветами и прочим. Но в таком случае смещение задаётся сразу и статически.

Подскажите пожалуйста, какая из идей может быть верной?

1) Прописать в массив сразу все координаты всех текстур. Т.е. помимо 9-ти координат примитива (пока пробую на обычном треугольнике) будут ещё 6 * 4 координат для текстур. И затем, в процессе работы программы, передавать в некую функцию аргумент, который будет значить текущее смещение для текущей текстуры.

2) С помощью uniform загружать не только текстуру, но и координаты текстуры в фрагментный шейдер. Тут встаёт вопрос, как это сделать? Это было бы значительно проще, по-моему. Но фрагментый шейдер описывает отдельные фрагменты, и координаты текстуры загружаются в формате vec2. Я понимаю, что в таком случае я не смогу загрузить сразу вес массив из 6-ти координат, и надо передавать каждые 2 координаты отдельно. Пробовал так:

```
        GLuint texLoc = glGetUniformLocation(ourShader.Program, "tex");
        GLuint texCoord = glGetUniformLocation(ourShader.Program, "texcoord");
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
        {
            glUniform2f(texCoord, vectorOfPrimitives[i].texcoord[j][0], vectorOfPrimitives[i].texcoord[j][1]);
        }
        glUniform1i(texLoc, texture);
```

И шейдер:

```
#version 330 core
in vec2 TexCoord;

out vec4 color;

uniform vec4 ourColor;
uniform vec2 texcoord;

uniform sampler2D ourTexture;

void main(){
    color = texture(ourTexture, TexCoord) * ourColor;
}
```

Это неправильно, но как ещё можно загрузить данные для каждой координаты в шейдер? И возможно ли это?

Comment: `... задаётся сразу и статически` — VAO можно спокойно изменять, пока он выбран как текущий. Может быть, вы имели в виду VBO?

Comment: `текстура лежит в массиве с координатами/цветами и прочим` — не путайте между собой собственно *текстуру* (хранящуюся отдельно и адресуемую через отдельный дескриптор) и *текстурные координаты*, которые действительно «вшиты» в геометрические данные модели как один из атрибутов её вершин.

Comment: Теперь по способам. Второй способ непригоден потому, что не удастся «оторвать» текстурные координаты от вершины, поместить их во внешний буфер, а в вершине оставить индекс. Корень проблемы — в усреднении вершинных атрибутов при получении их значения для растеризации точки где-нибудь внутри треугольника. Соответственно, дискретный индекс будет «размазан» и тем самым искажён.

Comment: А как думаете, если же, например, я задам координаты статически, в VBO (да, оговорился выше), а затем буду по некоторой комбинации клавиш менять текстуру?
Попробовал так сделать, но проблема в том, что крутить в цикле каждый раз bind текстуры - как-то неправильно...
Ну и плюсом ко всему как это сделать для каждого из примитивов?

Comment: Вынесите текстурные координаты в отдельные VBO (координаты для одной текстуры в один буфер, координаты для второй — в другой буфер и т. д. То есть не класть всё в единый VBO, как я думал в начале), а затем при необходимости перехода к новой текстуре выполните переключение текстуры (`glBindTexture()`) и буфера с текстурными координатами (`glBindAttribLocation()`).

Comment: А насчёт использования «bind» — пока вы не вызовите какой-нибудь `glGet...()` или `glDraw...()`, команды будут выполняться асинхронно и не станут влиять на производительность.

Comment: И ещё, как-то странно грузить текстурные координаты как uniform. Ведь параметры с таким типом являются общими и неизменными для всех вершин.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вторая идея неверна в корне, так как не получится «оторвать» текстурные координаты от вершины, поместить их во внешний буфер, а в вершине оставить индекс. Корень проблемы — в усреднении значения вершинных атрибутов при растеризации точки внутри треугольника. Соответственно, дискретные повершинные индексы будет «размазаны» и тем самым искажёны.

Первая идея в чистом виде тоже неприемлема, так как ведёт к значительному увеличению размера массива вершинных атрибутов. Это плохо тем, что при нехватке в видеопамяти даже одного байта весь этот большой массив будет постоянно вытесняться в основное ОЗУ и возвращаться обратно, что сильно ударит по производительности.

Однако эту идею можно улучшить выносом координат в отдельные VBO, чтобы координаты для каждой из текстур лежали в отдельном буфере. Это работает, потому что функция `glVertexAttribPointer()`, задающая источник данных для указанного атрибута, *копирует* идентификатор текущего VBO в свои внутренние параметры. Как результат, мы можем привязать `glBindVertexArray()`-ом какой-то VBO, разметить в нём атрибуты, затем привязать другой VBO и разметить в нём ещё какие-то атрибуты (при этом шейдер продолжит помнить о первом буфере и о том, что и как из него можно вытащить).

Тогда процесс визуализации может выглядеть в коде следующим образом.

*Пусть у нас имеются идентификаторы всех вершинных атрибутов, которые были либо явно заданы при компиляции посредством `glBindAttribLocation()`, либо получены после компиляции силами `glGetAttribLocation()`.*

1. Если мы переключали шейдер вызовом `glUseProgram()`, и при этом у нас нет VAO, который бы хранил в себе всё состояние.

   1. Проходим по всем атрибутам и активируем их с помощью `glEnableVertexAttribArray()`.
   2. Привязываем первый, «основной» буфер вызовом `glBindVertexArray()`.
   3. Последовательно вызываем `glVertexAttribIPointer()`, указывая этим размещение всех атрибутов (кроме текстурных координат) в буфере.
   4. Привязываем другой буфер, с координатами, соответствующими нужной нам текстуре.

      *Чтобы упростить себе жизнь, можно хранить `std::map`, ключами которого являются пары «текстура – mesh», а полезной нагрузкой — идентификатор VBO-буфера.*
   5. Вызываем `glVertexAttribIPointer()` для атрибута текстурных координат.
2. Если же у нас есть VAO — активируем его и, ...

   - если он подготовлен, производим шаги 1.4 и 1.5;
   - если он только что создан, производим все действия в шаге 1.
3. Визуализируем mesh с помощью `glDrawElements()`. И да, текстура к этому моменту уже должна быть активирована.